# Are there any performance penalties when using a TEXT as a Primary Key?

Tags: cassandra, cql

If yes, what would the data model look like if I want to have a unique TEXT field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cassandra primary key. performance implications if integer vs varchar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692446/cassandra-primary-key-performance-implications-if-integer-vs-varchar)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  Regardless of data type used, Cassandra stores all data on disk (including primary key values) as hex byte arrays. In terms of performance, the datatype of the primary key really doesn't matter.

The only case where it would matter, is in token/node distribution.  This is because the generated token for `"12345"` as text will be different from the token generated for `12345` as a bigint:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE textaskey (key text PRIMARY KEY, value text);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE longaskey (key bigint PRIMARY KEY, value text);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO textaskey (key, value) VALUES ('12345','12345');
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO longaskey (key, value) VALUES (12345,'12345');
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT token(key),value FROM textaskey ;

 token(key)          | value
---------------------+-------
 2375712675693977547 | 12345

(1 rows)
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT token(key),value FROM longaskey;

 token(key)          | value
---------------------+-------
 3741197147323682197 | 12345

(1 rows)
```

But even in this example, one shouldn't perform faster/different than the other.

Comment: Wouldn't there be slight differences because hashing TEXT is usually slower than hashing Numbers or Integers.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed. I would agree though that it mostly won't be noticeable

Comment: Yes, hashing a string takes longer than a number, but from a Cassandra query perspective, you shouldn't notice it @desertice