# Whats the difference between CQL data type VARCHAR vs TEXT?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

1. Difference between CQL data type TEXT vs Varchar ?
2. Any functional limitations ?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No.  As you can see in the [CQL data types](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) doc, both `text` and `varchar` are UTF-8 strings.
2. No.  I answered a similar question here: [Are there any performance penalties when using a TEXT as a Primary Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191761/are-there-any-performance-penalties-when-using-a-text-as-a-primary-key/28194884#28194884)
   Basically, all data is stored on-disk as a hex byte array, so it really doesn't matter.